# Can I use Lombok with GWT in Development Mode?

Tags: java, gwt, lombok

I tried to follow the [official instructions](http://projectlombok.org/setup/gwt.html) on running a lomboked GWT project in dev mode, but either I'm doing something wrong, or this doesn't work with current versions of GWT anymore?

The error I get is:

> "The method setA(int) is undefined for the type MyData".

MyData is simple:

```
@Data
public class MyData {
  private int a;
}
```

I'm specifying

> -javaagent:/path/to/lombok.jar=ECJ

in my Eclipse Run Configuration (as a VM argument).

I also tried playing around with

> -Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/lombok.jar

, as well as starting dev mode from my ant file, etc.

The problem is, that I'm mostly just guessing how the whole setup should work, so instead of troubleshooting my poor attempts, I'd like to ask how a correct setup would look like?

Comment: I use [delombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html) to cut off some magic and hackery (Lombok is a big hack in itself, even its author acknowledged it), and it works unsurprisingly well.

Answer (score 4):

You've probably got it working by now, but I can confirm it does work with GWT2.4 / Eclipse 3.7 . The only option needed is the -javaagent VM arg, and adding lombok.jar to the classpath/buildpath.

I think there's some issues when you first start to use it, to do with either the gwt-unitCache folder, and the war/WEB-INF/classes folder, clearing these is probably a good step when setting it up !

Comment: Deleting the "gwt-unitCache" folder did the trick! I copied the web app project from another system, together with this cache folder. After clearing it, the error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've stumbled upon [Issue 393](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/393). If that's the case you can try the latest [edge release](https://projectlombok.org/download-edge.html)

Disclosure: I'm one of the project lombok developers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, this really looks like the new issue 320! However, I just downloaded the edge release in your link, installed it, and reconfigured my project, but unfortunately the problem remains. My GWT project is really simple: Just the usual example GWT project plus a call to the MyData object (From the client side! It works perfectly on the server side of course)...

Comment: Can you please file a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/list)?

Comment: The [Lombok issue tracker](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues) is now on github.