# Lombok is not working with GWT compile

Tags: gwt, compilation, getter-setter, lombok, gwt-compiler

I have been trying to use Lombok as the latest solution (in some desperation) to my getters/setters problem (I've tried GWT generators, and annotation processors, but Lombok looks like it might be the answer) but I've run into a problem. If I put the annotations in my class:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class MyModel extends MyAbstractModel {
    private Integer uid;
    //...
}
```

Then, as expected, Eclipse can see the new methods. I have placed **lombok.jar** in **/lib** and put it in the build path, yet when I try and use GWT compile I get errors to the effect that none of the getters/setters exist. If I put them in manually, compile works fine.

I can't work out what is going wrong here, I've even put the `-javaagent` reference into the VM arguments but no cigar. It just looks like the lombok annotation processors aren't working when GWT compiles (and I've also tried deleting the *unitCache* but that doesn't work either).

I really don't want to have to write these getters and setters by hand, I have a good 50 or so models, and some of them have 20-30 properties.

Comment: (yes I have seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414674/can-i-use-lombok-with-gwt-in-development-mode but it's not exactly the same problem)

Comment: As a workaround, use [delombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html) to generate sources with getters and setters and point GWT at those generated sources.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to have worked when I use `@Getter @Setter` before each property name, but not when I put any annotations before the classname.

Comment: Hi, so finally, is it worth trying to use Lombok ? I mean, configuration in eclipse and GWT etc are difficult for me (I use GWT/GAE). Moreover, if each time there is some extra manip (re-generate sources), if some cases does not work (like @GTF said)...it s a lot of pain...Is there an alternative to Lombok ? Does it works with SuperDevMode ? Tks.